# Ruby TTY prompt undefined variable or method

Tags: ruby, tty

So for an assignment, I am building a simple choose your own adventure terminal game.

I have an undefined local variable or method error I cant get past.

```html
prompt.select("Do you stop to listen? Do you leave the path to investigate? or do you spur your horse on faster?") do |menu|
    menu.choice "Stop to listen", -> {paragraph_4}
    menu.choice "Leave path and investigate", -> {paragraph_5}
    menu.choice "Spur horse on faster", -> {paragraph_7}
  
  end
```

There are three paragraphs stored in each of the 4 ruby files-

```html
prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

$paragraph_4 = def paragraph_4

prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

puts ""
puts "" 
puts "   Stopping to listen it seems whatever is moving in the brush is doing the same. Your horse stamps a foot impatiently."

prompt.select("Will you dismount? Do you call out? or do you continue on your way?") do |menu|
  menu.choice "Dismount", -> {paragraph_7}
  menu.choice "Call out", -> {paragraph_8}
  menu.choice "Continue", -> {paragraph_7}

end

$paragraph_5 = def paragraph_5
uts ""
puts "" 
puts ""
puts "  Suddenly a giant spider leaps from the brush and burys its huge fangs in your neck."
puts "" 
puts "  YOU HAVE DIED
```

This works only for the first paragraph of each file. As in if I make the first selection on the prompt it works however the second or third-

game.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method` paragraph_2' for main:Object (NameError)

I don't understand why?

```html
prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

$paragraph_1 = def paragraph_1 

prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

   puts ""
   puts ""
   puts "  'Ah the north road, a wise choice friend as your way will meander towards Ered Mithrin and Durins folk of the Grey Mountains'
  'Perhaps like Gandalf and his companions who whence this way you will find Erebor the lonely mountain, whereby Smaug the Terrible met his end.'
  'Now friend the hour grows late and you best away lest you not find a clearing within the woods to light a fire for camp at night.
  'Bidding the kind old man well and flicking a silver coin his way you nudge your horse with your knees and head towards the woods.'
  'As you approach the branchs of the dark and twisted trees seem to reach out and their trunks rear up and lean forward to engulf you. Soon the space'
  'between the boughs becomes thinner and thinner and although what seemed like moments ago late afternoon now seems like a twighlight under the weight of the ancient forest."

  "As you walk deeper into the dark woods you hear a rustling and from the corner of your eye you see movement to your left"

  prompt.select("Do you stop to listen? Do you leave the path to investigate? or do you spur your horse on faster?") do |menu|
    menu.choice "Stop to listen", -> {paragraph_4}
    menu.choice "Leave path and investigate", -> {paragraph_5}
    menu.choice "Spur horse on faster", -> {paragraph_7}

  end 


  
  $paragraph_2 = def paragraph_2 

  prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

  puts ""
  puts ""
  puts "  'Ah the middle way, a sensible choice friend as your way will take you through the lands of the Sindarin or Silvan Elves and Thranduil's realm'
  'Now friend the hour grows late and you best away lest you not find a clearing within the woods to light a fire for camp at night.
  'Bidding the kind old man well and flicking a silver coin his way you nudge your horse with your knees and head towards the woods.'
  'As you approach the branchs of the dark and twisted trees seem to reach out and their trunks rear up and lean forward to engulf you. Soon the space'
  'between the boughs becomes thinner and thinner and although what seemed like moments ago late afternoon now seems like a twighlight under the weight of the ancient forest."
  ""
  "As you walk deeper into the dark woods you hear a rustling and from the corner of your eye you see movement to your left"

  prompt.select("Do you stop to listen? Do you leave the path to investigate? or do you spur your horse on faster?") do |menu|
    menu.choice "Stop to listen", -> {paragraph_4}
    menu.choice "Leave path and investigate", -> {paragraph_5}
    menu.choice "Spur horse on faster", -> {paragraph_7}
  
  end
```

Comment: Lambdas are closures. Where is the #paragraph_2 method defined?

Comment: I have added another code snippet if you could take a look Todd would be appreciated.

Comment: You’re calling methods inside lambdas. The methods are not in scope.

Comment: You’re also assigning methods to global variables, but they aren’t lambdas and you never try to call them. It’s unclear why you think this would work, and your examples don’t really explain your thought process sufficiently to help further.

Comment: I am new to Ruby and have only been learning coding for 3 months so forgive my ignorance. What I want to do is branch out from each paragraph via the tty prompt and then again until the conclusion of the story. If you could advise how this would work it would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want to do:

```
require 'tty-prompt'

class MyGame
  attr_accessor :prompt

  def initialize
    @prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
  end

  def paragraph_1
    prompt.select("What do you do?") do |menu|
      menu.choice "Stop to listen",->{paragraph_2}
      menu.choice "Leave path and investigate",->{paragraph_3}
      menu.choice "Spur horse on faster",->{paragraph_4}
    end
  end

  def paragraph_2
    # TODO: implement choices; use paragraph_1 as an example
    prompt.select('Paragraph 2') do |menu|
      menu.choice 'P2 Choice 1'
      menu.choice 'P2 Choice 2'
      menu.choice 'P2 Choice 3'
    end
  end

  def paragraph_3
    # TODO: implement choices; use paragraph_1 as an example
    prompt.select('Paragraph 3') do |menu|
      menu.choice 'P3 Choice 1'
      menu.choice 'P3 Choice 2'
      menu.choice 'P3 Choice 3'
    end
  end

  def paragraph_4
    # TODO: implement choices; use paragraph_1 as an example
    prompt.select('Paragraph 4') do |menu|
      menu.choice 'P4 Choice 1'
      menu.choice 'P4 Choice 2'
      menu.choice 'P4 Choice 3'
    end
  end
end

my_game = MyGame.new
my_game.paragraph_1
```

I don't suggest defining your methods in `$` global variables. Classes/Modules are better ways to organize your code.

Also, I would suggest a better naming scheme. For example:

- cool_path1
- cool_path1_choice1
- cool_path1_choice2
- cool_path1_choice3

Or something similar. You can break this up into even more Classes/Modules into different files if want.

I can see this getting quite complicated too though. Internally, you could store some type of state (what choices our *hero* has made) and decide from there.

Don't be afraid to ask your teacher for help. That's one of the purposes of teachers. Maybe your teacher can help you with the code and/or design.